# Calculating array combinations using recursion

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I wish to input an n*m array and the resulting output be an array containing the different combinations of the row elements. 
Here's an example to clarify (albeit an extremely simple case):

I wish to input an array of the following shape:

```
[[1, 2, 3]
[2, 5, 6]]
```

And wish to receive the following output:

```
[[1,2], [1,5], [1,6], [2,5], [2,6], [3,2], [3,5], [3,6]]
```

As you can see `[2,2]` is not included because of repetition.

I can write quick and dirty code containing nested for loops when the input dimensions are know a priori:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6]]
m = len(A[0])    
for i in range(0, m):      
    for j in range(0, m):
            if A[0][i]!=A[1][j]:                     #check and eliminate repetition
                combined.append([A[0][i],A[1][j])
                choice_num.append([i+1, j+1])    #See (**) below
```

I would really like to know how to implement this as a recursive function so given some input n-D array, A, one can simply call it as:

```
recursive_looper(A)
```

(**) Another feature that I would like is for the function to output the column number corresponding to the element used in the combination so we get two outputs:

```
element values:   [[1,2], [1,5], [1,6], [2,5], [2,6], [3,2], [3,5], [3,6]]
element position: [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,2], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]]
```

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Edit: I am open to any solution that can achieve the desired output. Recursion was simply the first thing that came to mind.

Edit 2 (Extended capabilities): This code must not be restricted to a specific list input shape but be extensible to any array of shape (n,m).
I'll provide an example for where the code breaks down. The work-around was implementing n-1 conditional statements, **which I would like to avoid** because the array shape must be known a priori.

```
A = [[2, 4, 1, 11, 3], [3, 2, 1, 4, 11], [2, 3, 4, 17, 13]]
```

If I do not make any modifications to your indexing/filter I receive the following output for the 'filtered' list:

```
#[[2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 17], [2, 3, 13], [2, 1, 2], ..., [3, 11, 13]]
```

Immediately I notice that it only compared element position 0 with position 1 for 'likeness', hence why the first combination contains two 2's.
I can make a modification to the Index grabber and filter loop which looks like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(projects_master)-2):
    indexes = [idx for idx, t in enumerate(prod) if t[i] == t[i+1] or t[i]==t[i+2] or t[i+1] == t[i+2] ]

res = []
for i in range(0, len(A)-2):
    res.append(list(filter( lambda v: v[i] != v[i+1] and v[i] != v[i+2] and v[i+1] != v[i+2], prod)))
result = [list(t) for t in res[0]]
```

This **does** give the correct output, but like I said, I needed to write out n-1  t[i] and v[i] conditions. How can this be done automatically?

**EDIT 3 - FINAL**
Thanks a bunch to those who provided different approaches to help me achieve the same end goal. I took some insight from each and wrote something that makes sense to me and seems to function well for any input. The code which filters duplicates and removes them from the combinations is shown below:

```
ind_remove = []
for i in range(0, len(prod)):
    if len(prod[i]) != len(set(prod[i])):
        ind_remove.append(i)

adder=0
for i in ind_remove:
    del prod[i-adder]
    adder=adder+1   #takes into account change in indices after an element is deleted.
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use recursion for this problem? Recursion is usually pretty slow in Python, and its depth is limited by the interpreter (usually to 1000 calls deep, but you can adjust it with `sys.setrecursionlimit`). There doesn't seem to be any particular benefit to solving this problem recursively, your iterative solution does it about as elegantly as possible.

Comment: The main reason was so that the code can take any shape array as input and generate the required number of nested loops. If the input was known to have 8 rows, then I could certainly write out 8 nested for loops. Just looking for a more autonomous solution.

Comment: Then I think this is an XY problem. You're asking about recursion, but what you *really* want to know about is "how can I make this work for any number of rows?". Recursion probably isn't the best way!

Comment: You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product to generate the combinations! Check my answer below!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it's been updated!

Comment: Cool, will update my answer for this case in some time

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I was able to combine aspects of your answer with pieces from other answers and am happy with my result, so don't spend anymore of your time on this problem :) Cheers!

Comment: @Blckknght using `setrecursionlimit` is trying to stand on a broken leg. Increasing the limit just means that it will break when the computation gets bigger - you're just allowing more memory to be wasted. It's possible to write recursive functions in python that don't grow the stack, so maybe start there.

Comment: @user633183: I agree that fiddling with the recursion limit is usually not a practical fix to Python's recursion issues. Usually you're either working on such a small dataset that the recursion limit (and the poor performance) won't matter, or you're working on such a large dataset that the performance issues are going to be totally crippling so you should switch to a different algorithm instead of trying to fiddle with the recursion. I'm not sure what you're referring to about not growing the stack. Python doesn't do tail call optimization, so there's not much you can do about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the required combinations, which works like a cartesion product between two sets to generate the combinations.

So it the lists have been `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, the cartesian product within the sublists will be
`[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]`

```
from itertools import product

a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6]]

# Generate all possible products, *a gives you two lists
prod = list(product(*a))
#[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 5), (3, 6)]

#Get the list of duplicate indexes
indexes = [idx for idx, t in enumerate(prod) if t[0] == t[1] ]
print(indexes)
#[3]

#Remove tuples who are duplicates
res = list(filter( lambda v: v[0] != v[1], prod))
print(res)
#[(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 5), (3, 6)]

#Convert the tuples to list
result = [list(t) for t in res]
print(result)
#[[1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Devesh! This is just what I was looking for. Is there anyway to grab the indices of the removed tuples (in this case it'd return a 3)? Given this information I could create the "element position" list.

Comment: One last thing for robustness... I notice your duplicate tuple remover requires m-1 conditional statements where m is the number of columns in a. Is there anyway to perform this check if we do not know how many columns we have? This will be my last question - I promise ;)

Comment: Which line of code? My duplicate remover is a `filter` combined with a lambda function which runs in linear time and only considers non-duplicate elements!

Comment: Sorry, it's the line `indexes = [idx for idx, t in enumerate(prod) if t[0] == t[1] ]` it seems to me like this checks if elements in adjacent rows are identical but if we input something of the sort `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,7,8]]` we will still have the combination `(1,4,1)` returned. I realize I wasn't explicit with what I meant by 'duplicates'. It's not just identical tuples I want removes like `(2,2)` but any combination that contains a repeated number.

Comment: Yes I can surely make that happen! Let me give it a shot! Can you update your new list, and correct me, but you want all elements in the tuple to be unique right!

Comment: I want the input list to vary in its size. For example I'd like for a user to be able to enter an array of shape (3,5) or of shape (6, 8) and the code would be versatile enough to handle it. And yes, you are correct, I would like all elements in the tuple to be unique.

Comment: Please update the question with this information for better readability!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that iterates over the items of the first list of the given list of lists and merge each item with the combinations from the recursive calls:

```
def nonrepetitive_product(lists):
    if not lists:
        yield []
        return
    first, *rest = lists
    combinations = list(nonrepetitive_product(rest))
    for item in first:
        for combination in combinations:
            if item not in combination:
                yield [item, *combination]
```

so that given:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6]]
```

`list(nonrepetitive_product(l))` returns:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution is closest to my original asking, however Devesh pointed me to a clever workout to avoid recursion. Nonetheless, your answer is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the positions and values for any number of rows, you'd be better off using `itertools.product` and `enumerate` together. Filtering is a little tricky, but it can be done:

```
import itertools

A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [7, 8, 3]]

prod = itertools.product(*map(enumerate, A))     # yields ((i,x),(j,y),(k,z),...) nested tuples
transposed = ([*zip(*pairs)] for pairs in prod)  # yields ((i,j,k,...), (x,y,z,...)) 2-tuples
filtered = [(ijk, xyz) for ijk, xyz in transposed if len(xyz) == len(set(xyz))] # filter dupes

indexes, values = zip(*filtered) # you might find `filtered` more useful than separate lists
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your method using `if len(xyz) == len(set(xyz))` put me in the right direction to be able to filter duplicates regardless of the input list size. I've included the filtering code in Edit 3 of the original code.